# Android Notification not displaying action buttons

Tags: java, android, notifications, audio-player, android-music-player

Below is the method I am using to build a notification for a media player application. Currently, the song information is being displayed correctly but the action buttons for prev, play, next are not being displayed.

This is what is displayed with the notification after calling buildNotification();

[image]

```
private void buildNotification(Notification.Action action) {
    String ID = "sage.musicplayer.Service.MusicService";

    /*Bitmap albumArtBitmap = null;
    if(album_art != null) {
        try {
            albumArtBitmap = Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).asBitmap().load(album_art).into(100, 100).get();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else if(albumID > -1) {
        albumArtBitmap = musicUtils.getAlbumArt(albumID);
    }else{
        albumArtBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.new_album_art);
    }*/

    Intent intent = new Intent(MusicService.this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
    Intent intentPrev = new Intent(ACTION_PREV);
    Intent intentPlayPause;
    if(isPng())
        intentPlayPause = new Intent(ACTION_PAUSE);
    else
        intentPlayPause = new Intent(ACTION_PLAY);
    Intent intentNext = new Intent(ACTION_NEXT);
    PendingIntent pendingPrev = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentPrev, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
    PendingIntent pendingPlayPause = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentPlayPause, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
    PendingIntent pendingNext = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentNext, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    notification.setContentTitle(songTitle)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setChannelId(ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setContentText(songArtist)
            .setLargeIcon(musicUtils.getAlbumArt(albumID))
            .setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle().setMediaSession(MediaSessionCompat.Token.fromToken(mediaSession.getSessionToken())))
            .addAction(R.drawable.prev, "Prev", pendingPrev)
            .addAction(R.drawable.playbutton, "Play", pendingPlayPause)
            .addAction(R.drawable.next, "Next", pendingNext);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification.build());
}
```

Comment: Are you using ExoPlayer? It should come with a class where you pass the MediaSession and a few other things inside and it will just build the notification and manage everything for you.

Comment: I might consider using ExoPlayer if I can't find a solution. That seems very convenient. My application is already built(unfortunately) using Android's MediaPlayer. Changing to exoplayer would be annoying since much of the application is built to use MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your drawables (R.drawable.prev, etc) are vectorial and not images, it won't work. I had the same issue today.

Comment: The drawables used are next.png, prev.png, pausebutton.png, playbutton.png. When I press on their location while using the application there is a ripple effect as if the images are at the correct location but are not visible.

Comment: Did you create them using Android Studio "New" -> "Image Asset" and select "Notification Icons" as icon type ? If the drawables are not specific for notification icons, there can be graphical bugs like that

Comment: Thank you! I had not understood creating an Image Asset was necessary. Creating an image asset using the images caused the notification actions to appear correctly.

Comment: It is still somehow not working for me!

Comment: Beginning from Android 13, it doesn't take into account actions from the `MediaStyle`. Android 13 and above is using MediaSession. See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#ux